# Convert a json array to an hashmap<string,object>

Tags: java, jackson

I have an external parsed List type which is a json array, indeed this call

```
list.toString()
```

gives me this:

```
[{name=prop1, content=<something>},{name=prop2, content=<something>}]
```

The content could be anything, an array, a string, an int...
So I'd like to map that json array to something like

```
HashMap<String,Object> converted;
```

This would allow me to do this:

```
converted.get("prop1"); //this will give me the <something>
```

how could I do that?

Comment: Careful, that isn't JSON.

Comment: I believe you cannot do that directly... Either go through a parser, create POJOs or parse the JSON directly

Comment: It is a json array, how come it isn't json?

Comment: If they're just Strings, you could use something like [MapSplitter](./guava/src/com/google/common/base/).

Comment: Just because it has `[]` and `{}`, doesn't mean it is JSON. Look into the [JSON format](http://json.org/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this using JSON Parser. Get the JSON lib from here [json.simple](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

```
Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();

try {

  Object obj = parser.parse(list);

  JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray)obj;

  Iterator<JSONObject> iterator = jsonArray.iterator();
  while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       JSONObject jsonObj = iterator.next();
      String name = (String) jsonObject.get("name");
       Object content = (Object) jsonObject.get("content");
       map.put(name, content);
  }
} catch (ParseException p) { }
```

Comment: no..i forgot to add the code for parsing...now i have edited my code