# How I can parse JSON to Array in Java?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, post

Sorry for my limited english first.

I have a JSON sent from a POST request to my spring controller in Java.

I need parse this JSON to a Array. How I can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: use Google's `gson` library. And show us some code.

Comment: `this JSON` -- > Which JSON ?

Comment: @VinayakPingale `a JSON sent from a POST request` ;)

Comment: Similar Question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22644334/convert-a-json-array-to-an-hashmapstring-object/22644538#22644538

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another option would be to use [json-smart](https://code.google.com/p/json-smart/)

1. Convert JSON to an object
   `JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parseWithException(inputJsonInStringFormat);`
2. Retrieve array by using `get()` method
   `Integer [] intArray = (JSONArray) (JSONObject) jsonObj.get("arrayName");`

Answer (score 0):

using `javax.json` library, it should be something like:

```
JsonReader reader = Json.createReader(new FileInputStream(dir));
JsonArray re = (JsonObject) reader.read() ;
double[] ret = new double[jre.size()];
for ( int i = 0; i<jre.size(); i++)
    ret[i] = Double.parseDouble( jre.getString(i) );
```

It does depend, however, on what the Json file looks like. Maybe it's a Json object, with one parameter which has an array as a value, or something. I hope this code can give you a headstart though.

Answer (score 0):

you should not handle it by your-self let spring mvc do it for you, once you enabled spring mvc annotation you will have json converter implicitly, you will need only to add jackson jars to classpath, check this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DnDCJjjSiu8 , your may face problem if want to send JSON as ["value1","value2"], in this case you will need to make custom JsonDeserializer